# Clicking on List-Unsubscribe for low reputation senders

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, there's an unsubscribe option but it's [only shown for senders with a high reputation](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2009/07/unsubscribing-made-easy.html) when "*the most basic requirements are including a standard "List-Unsubscribe" header in your email with a "mailto" URL"*.

What if a low reputation sender does it and I decide to trust it despite what Gmail thinks on the matter? Is there any way to use that unsubscribe link despite what Gmail wants?

Comment: it's more about safety because it's unwise to unsubscribe from unknown source coz it could trigger a chain reaction to send you more spam than ever.

Comment: But sometimes we're talking about major corporations that already know my address so I have nothing to lose. In any case, I'm not asking to make it a default, just if there's an advanced way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there's no answer, I'll write this in advance - right now my solution is to:

1. See the source code
2. Find "List-Unsubscribe: " (with a space) and copy the relevant data
3. Compose a new message
4. Paste the data there and send away
   [image]